# how to use link_to_unless in rails for filetype

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

Is there any easy way to use link_to_unless to only exclude gifs?  Basically, I want the link to be inactive/removed for images uploaded that are gifs.

```
<span itemprop="photo">
   <%= link_to image_tag(place.image.url(:medium)), place, class: "hover" %>
</span>
```

I'm using the paperclip gem for S3, this is what I have in my models for which I add images.  I do not have a model just for images.

```
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the content type through the [`Attachment#content_type`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb#L288-L290) method. You can test if the image is a gif with

```
place.image.content_type == 'image/gif'
```

Hence what you want is

```
<span itemprop="photo">
   <%= link_to_unless place.image.content_type == 'image/gif', image_tag(place.image.url(:medium)), place, class: "hover" %>
</span>
```

The first argument of `link_to_unless` just takes a condition. In this case it checks if the image url ends in `.gif`.

However, this looks like too much logic for the view. I would recommend putting this in a decorator instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
<%= link_to_unless place.image.url(:medium).match(/\.gif$/), image_tag(place.image.url(:medium)), place, class: "hover" %>
```

OR use helper method as the following:

```
def image_not_gif(url)
  unless url.match(/\.gif$/)
    image_tag(place.image.url(:medium)
  end
end
```

and then use this code:

```
<%= link_to image_not_gif(place.image.url(:medium)), place, class: "hover" %>
```

Comment: Thanks Mohamed, for some reason I can't get either of those to work.  For the latter, it keeps telling me the method is not defined, even though I defined it in the model.  I am missing something?

Comment: actually you need to add this method in application_helper.rb file as helper method